# How to remove keys from sqlite that aren't listed in a list?

Tags: java, sqlite, arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> url = new ArrayList<String>();
```

contains

```
stuffcom123, 1603932831196 
stuffcom124, 1603932831196 
stuffcom125, 1603932831196 
stuffcom126, 1603932831196


 public void insert(String url, double time) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO villages (url,time) VALUES(?,?)";

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pstmt.setString(1, url);
        pstmt.setDouble(2, time);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

So I've got a list of urls. And I want to record the System.currentTimeMillis() of the last time I visited each specific url in a sqlite database.

My question is, how do I remove all entries in the sqlite database, that aren't listed in my url array list.

Do I just make a loop from 0 to end and individually check if each key exists in the url arraylist? or is there some better trick?

Comment: `delete from <table> where url not in (.......)` ?

Comment: String sql = "DELETE FROM villages WHERE url = (?)";

 pstmt.setString(1, url.toString());

Something.... something... Hmm this wouldn't work because it would be comparing a giant string looking for one entry